# Is it possible to share both text and a photo from Flutter image_picker using flutter_share or another share plugin?

Tags: listview, flutter, share, flutter-dependencies

Using the flutter_share plugin I can successfully share text from my firestore collections in my Flutter ListView with:

```
child: IconButton(
icon: Icon(
  Icons.share,
   onPressed: () => Share.share(
   '${(snapshot.data.documents[index]['title'])}',
       ))),
```

I have now added a new flutter listtile section to the ListView that includes a photo from the image_picker plugin, where users can select a photo from their gallery or take a new photo and append it beneath the firestore data text.

```
 void _openImagePicker(BuildContext context) {
 showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) {
   return Container(
     height: 180.0,
     padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
   child: Column(
     children: [
     Text('Choose photo',
       style:TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
       SizedBox(height: 10.0),
       FlatButton(
         textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
         child: Text('Use Camera'),
       onPressed: () {
           _getImage(context, ImageSource.camera);
       },),
       FlatButton(
         textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,child:
       Text('Open Gallery'),
         onPressed: () {
           _getImage(context, ImageSource.gallery);
         },),

     ]
   ),);
 });
 }
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Column(
   children: <Widget>[
     OutlineButton(
     onPressed: () {
       _openImagePicker(context);
     },
     child:Row(
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
         children: <Widget>[
           Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
           SizedBox(
             width:1.0,
           ),
           // Text('Add Image'),
         ]
     ),//Row
 ),//outline button

    SizedBox(height: 10.0),
     _imageFile == null ?  Text('Add an Image') : Image.file(_imageFile,
         fit: BoxFit.cover,
         height: 200.0,
      width: 200.0,       
       alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
     ),
   ],
 );}}
```

My question is, is there a way with either this flutter_share plugin or another plugin to combine both the new image with the original shared firestore text, so users can share both text and the photo combined, instead of just the text? Or is it only possible to send one or another?

The image won't be stored in Firestore, only the text, so the image could be taken with the users camera or uploaded from their gallery, then appended to the shared text.

---

Here is full code with esys share added, it is not sending the image_picker image

```
class ImageInput extends StatefulWidget {


 @override
 _ImageInputState createState() => _ImageInputState();
    }

class _ImageInputState extends State<ImageInput> {


  File _imageFile;

  void _getImage(BuildContext context, ImageSource source){
   ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source, maxWidth: 200.0).then((File image){
   setState((){
    _imageFile = image;
  //        _imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
  //        List<int> imageBytes = await _imageFile.readAsBytes();
  //        var uint8List = Uint8List.fromList(imageBytes);


  });
  Navigator.pop(context);

  });
 }


  void _openImagePicker(BuildContext context) {

  showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    height: 180.0,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
  child: Column(
    children: [
    Text('Choose photo',
      style:TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
      SizedBox(height: 10.0),
      FlatButton(
        textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        child: Text('Use Camera'),
      onPressed: () {
          _getImage(context, ImageSource.camera);
      },),
      FlatButton(
        textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,child:
      Text('Open Gallery'),
        onPressed: () {
          _getImage(context, ImageSource.gallery);
        },)

    ]
  ),);
 });
 }


 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Column(
 children: <Widget>[
    OutlineButton(
    onPressed: () {
      _openImagePicker(context);
    },
    child:Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
          SizedBox(
            width:1.0,
          ),
          // Text('Add Image'),
        ]
    ),//Row
  ),//outline button

   SizedBox(height: 10.0),
    _imageFile == null ?  Text('Add an Image') : Image.file(_imageFile,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        height: 200.0,
     width: 200.0,
     // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
    ),

    MaterialButton(
      child: Text('Share mixed'),
      onPressed: () async => await _shareMixed(),
    ),

  ],
);
}
}


Future<void> _shareMixed() async {
try {
final ByteData bytes1 = await rootBundle.load('_imageFile');
//final ByteData bytes2 = await rootBundle.load('assets/image2.png');
// final ByteData bytes3 = await rootBundle.load('assets/addresses.csv');

await Share.files(
    'esys images',
    {
      '_imageFile': bytes1.buffer.asUint8List(),
      //'bluedan.png': bytes2.buffer.asUint8List(),
      //'addresses.csv': bytes3.buffer.asUint8List(),
    },
    '*/*',
    text: 'My optional text.');
} catch (e) {
print('error: $e');
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/esys_flutter_share

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:esys_flutter_share/esys_flutter_share.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';

class ImageInput extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImageInputState createState() => _ImageInputState();
}

class _ImageInputState extends State<ImageInput> {
  File _imageFile;

  void _getImage(BuildContext context, ImageSource source) {
    ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source, maxWidth: 200.0).then((File image) {
      setState(() {
        _imageFile = image;
        //        _imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
        //        List<int> imageBytes = await _imageFile.readAsBytes();
        //        var uint8List = Uint8List.fromList(imageBytes);
      });
      Navigator.pop(context);
    });
  }

  Future<void> _shareImageAndText() async {
    try {
      List<int> imageBytes = await _imageFile.readAsBytes();
      var uint8List = Uint8List.fromList(imageBytes);
      await Share.file('esys image', 'esys.jpg', uint8List, 'image/jpeg',
          text: 'My optional text.');
    } catch (e) {
      print('error: $e');
    }
  }

  void _openImagePicker(BuildContext context) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Container(
            height: 180.0,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: Column(children: [
              Text(
                'Choose photo',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              FlatButton(
                textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                child: Text('Use Camera'),
                onPressed: () {
                  _getImage(context, ImageSource.camera);
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                child: Text('Open Gallery'),
                onPressed: () {
                  _getImage(context, ImageSource.gallery);
                },
              )
            ]),
          );
        });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        OutlineButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _openImagePicker(context);
          },
          child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 1.0,
                ),
                // Text('Add Image'),
              ]), //Row
        ), //outline button

        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
        _imageFile == null
            ? Text('Add an Image')
            : Image.file(
                _imageFile,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                height: 200.0,
                width: 200.0,
                // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              ),

        MaterialButton(
          child: Text('Share mixed'),
          onPressed: () async => await _shareImageAndText(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ImageInput(),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It is conflicting with the original share package package:share/share.dart, and enabling only esys returns errors with just text share - Share.text('my text title', 'This is my text to share with other applications.', 'text/plain');

Comment: And what would I substitute for the image 'eyse.png', since I am getting image from image_picker - would it just be my variable '_imageFile' ?

Comment: onPressed: () async => await _shareMixed(), also does not work  for my IconButton. Are there better examples of this that I can look at to modify for my code? As it is now it is unusable.

Comment: It seems to this package has bug.

Comment: So it is not possible to share an image, only text? I'm beginning to wish I never heard of flutter and learned something else instead.Everything has bugs in flutter.

Comment: the key is to share Uint8List. you can use _imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
        List<int> imageBytes = await _imageFile.readAsBytes();
        var uint8List = Uint8List.fromList(imageBytes);

Comment: this package's issue is here https://github.com/esysberlin/esys-flutter-share/issues

Comment: Where would all that go in the example code? error: The await expression can only be used in an async function and error: Undefined name 'Uint8List' when replacing _imageFile =

Comment: I need to reproduce, please post your full code in one file to allow me check it or share it on github.

Comment: I have updated my answer and full code. you can check it.

Comment: you are a genius. Would you know how to display firestore string for this text, it worked in the other 'flutter_share' plugin with '${(snapshot.data.documents[index]['title'])}' but that does not work with esys inside this function (or should I post another separate question)? Thank you.

Comment: I do not have  firestore related experience. can not help. I suggest you can post another question. so more people can help you.

Comment: Do you mean Navigator.push to another page?

Comment: _imageFile = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source, imageQuality: 70);

Comment: I have to combine both the text (from firestore string) and image (from image_picker) both on the same share method, I can't see how to do that since they are on different pages/classes. I thought just adding the class ImageInput(), to the main page that would inherit the same functions but it doesn't. So I can't share BOTH image and text at the same time.

Comment: I suggest you could post new question. because I do not have firestore related experience. thanks.

Comment: it doesn't work either way, it won't even share the image if the share function is on a different page, It doesn't carry the _imageFile along with the class ImageInput() - says _imageFile id undefined.

Comment: the most easy way is move  _imageFile declaration outside all class, you do not need to pass it.

Comment: I moved _imageFile and _getImage outside of class first so it's global and I get 'UNDEFINED' errors on main page for imagfile.

Comment: could you post to another question and provide full code. it would be easier to debug and more people can help you. thanks.